# Can't hide progress dialog in Flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a Flutter app that downloads json from an endpoint and then populates a UI. During the downloading, I am showing a progress indicator from the `progress_dialog` package. This issue I am having is that I cannot hide the dialog. Here is my widget build code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProgressDialog prog = ProgressDialog(context);
    prog.style(
        message: "Downloading...",
        messageTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo);
    prog.show();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(kAllStates[widget.stateAbbreviation]),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getGaugesForState(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            prog.hide();
            return _listView(snapshot, context);
          } else {
            return Align(child: Text('Loading...'));
          }
        },
      ),
      endDrawer: RFDrawer(),
    );
  }
```

The list view is returned and builds, but the progress dialog never hides. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing prog.hide(); with setState(() => prog.hide());

Comment: If that doesn't work try replacing prog.hide(); with Navigator.of(context).pop();

Comment: If that doesn't work try making the call to hide asynchronous.

Comment: If that doesn't work try replacing prog.hide(); with prog.hide.then((isHidden)=>print(isHidden));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ProgressDialog prog = ProgressDialog(context);
        prog.style(
            message: "Downloading...",
            messageTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo);
      
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(kAllStates[widget.stateAbbreviation]),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getGaugesForState(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    
    if (asyncSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      prog.show();
    }
              else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                prog.hide();
                return _listView(snapshot, context);
              } else {
                return Align(child: Text('Loading...'));
              }
            },
          ),
          endDrawer: RFDrawer(),
        );
      }
```

Comment: same results, prog.hide() gets called, but does nothing. Just to be thorough, I verified that prog is the same instance when .show() or .hide() are called.